# MediaPlayer isn't equal to null, but I still get null pointer exception when I try to use it

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I am making a music playing app in Android Java. I have a `MediaPlayer` object that is supposed to play the audio file selected in the default Android file chooser. This is how I am calling the file chooser:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Files"), Constants.FILE_PICKER_CODE);
```

And this is how I'm handling the callback:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Constants.FILE_PICKER_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the data from the file picker.
            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            if (clipData != null) {
                // Init queue var if necessary.
                if (queueTracks == null) { queueTracks = new ArrayList<>(); }

                // Clear current queue. TODO: Will change this when implementing multiple queues.
                queueTracks.clear();

                // Add the tracks to the queue list.
                for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    Uri uri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    // Add the URI's path to queue list.
                    queueTracks.add(new File(uri.getPath()).getPath());
                    Snackbar.make(parentLayout, new File(uri.getPath()).getPath(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // Now try to play the first track.
                try {
                    // TESTING... will try to play one track from the device's storage. THIS IS WHERE THINGS ARE GOING WRONG.
                    Uri audioUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(queueTracks.get(0)));
                    mainMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioUri);

                    if (mainMediaPlayer == null) {
                        Log.d("Media player", "null!!!");
                    }
                    mainMediaPlayer.start();

                    queueMode = true;
                    placeInQueue = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Error");
                    builder.setMessage(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
                    builder.show();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }

            else {
                // Single track mode. THIS WORKS FINE!
                Uri audioUri = data.getData();
                mainMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioUri);
                mainMediaPlayer.start();

                queueMode = false;
                placeInQueue = 0;
            }
            mainTrackSeekbar.setMax(mainMediaPlayer.getDuration());
            mainTrackSeekbar.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

I am receiving this unusual error, however:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference

The error is being thrown from the line that is `mainMediaPlayer.start();` on the if branch that is run when the user picks multiple files.

I logged what my `mainMediaPlayer` variables was, here are the result:

> mainMediaPlayer = null--checked on the if branch that is run when the user picks multiple files. EVEN AFTER initializing it and running `MediaPlayer.create()` it is still null for some reason.

For some reason, when I select one file it works fine, but when I select multiple it crashes with the null pointer exception above. How do I fix this and make the `MediaPlayer` play the first item the user selected?

Comment: `mainMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("file:///document/primary%3ADownload/Cold%20Journey-Creatorchords.mp3"));` -- this is evaluating to `null`. Since it has no chance of working on modern versions of Android, I suggest that you remove this line, or replace the hard-coded `Uri` with your actual `Uri` from your `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.. And, in your `else` branch, you are calling `mainMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`, and then you are overwriting `mainMediaPlayer`, which means that `new MediaPlayer()` is pointless.

Comment: Please read the Java doc of MediaPlayer.create: "returns a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed"

Comment: @CommonsWare I have modified my code to remove the redundant `new MediaPlayer()`s and get the `Uri` returned from the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, (see my post's edit), but to no avail. Why would the creation fail? The path seems valid.

Comment: `queueTracks.add(new File(uri.getPath()).getPath());` -- get rid of this. `getPath()` is utterly meaningless in this context. `queueTracks` needs to be a list of `Uri` objects, not strings.